# Reducing texture bindings in LibGDX when drawing text

Tags: libgdx, rendering, ui-design, batching

I'm making custom menus and buttons (I don't want to use scene2D) and I have everything in atlases, but when I draw a button, if it has text, the texture binding is always x2 because of the switching back and forth between the texture in the atlas and the bitmapfont.

(example of drawing order)

```
public void draw(SpriteBatch b){
   if(texture != null)
      texture.draw(b);

   if(text != null && !text.isEmpty())
      font.draw(b, "TEXT", x, y);
}
```

So as you see, if I have 3 buttons, each button will increase the texture binding x2. When using several buttons, texture draw/bind is maybe around the number 24. This hasn't cause noticeable performance issues yet (FPS stay at 60~61) but I want to know how I can reduce the number of bindings when drawing textures and fonts at the same time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make *two batches*, one for the buttons (texture) and one for the labels (bitmap font).

That is also why you normally batch draw-calls. Group the things using the same resources to reduce draw calls and expensive unbinding/binding of textures and shader-programs.

Comment: The OP's case is a typical pitfall of OOP thinking when it comes to designing a renderer: "each object should know how to draw itself", but that leads to a design that doesn't batch well.  Instead each object should add it's draw parameters to a render queue, and the render queue has a manager that then sorts into batches and does the actual drawing.

Comment: @MaximusMinimus sort of pit-fall. But less of OOP and more of teaching of OOP. OOP, you can perfectly well encapsulate the whole rendering process in each `object`, as long as it is *only the information* and *not the process* of rendering. Thus another piece of code (e.g. call it `system`) can then interpret the information and proceed with rendering it however optimized it can. What we did here is separating data from processing, in web-dev this is called MVC (Model-View-Controller). In game-dev it is called E(C)S (Entity-(Component-)System).

Comment: Yes, good point about information vs process.

Comment: I'd like to submit the answer from @MaximusMinimus as the accepted answer. I will be implementing that idea and see how it goes, but i have another question: Iif a send everything to a renderer with instructions on how to draw, suppose i want to draw some text, above it a texture with alpha at 50% (so you can see the text below it) and another text above the texture: How can i draw that in an orderly fashion, batching textures and bitmapfonts so as to reduce bindings, but still get the effect where text is drawn before a texture and text is drawn again above it?

Comment: @Jh62 - if you have to break a batch then you have to break a batch; there's an obvious tradeoff here.

Comment: @Jh62 if you abstract that into a UI system you would have two batches per *ui-layer*. A layer being a window on top of another (assuming that is what you want to do with the 50% texture stuff)

Comment: @dot_Sp0T I will take that into account. What i have is a background and a menu that once you open it up, you can open submenus that stack on top of another with a little offset, but you can partialy see always behind the last one.

Comment: @Jh62 very fancy, you'll def go for two draw passes per z-level then